# Textbox is invisible and the location of popup overlapps the label below it

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my WPF application, originally I had a textbox.

```
<Window x:Class="Tester.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Test" Height="600" Width="800" >
<StackPanel Margin="10" >
    <Label Content="_Dial String:" Target="{Binding ElementName=txtDialString}" />
    <TextBox Name="txtDialString" />
    <Label Content="_Number of Calls to Generate:" Target="{Binding ElementName=txtCalls}" />
  <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox Name="txtCalls" Text="{Binding ElementName=sliderCalls,
            Path=Value,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="22"/>
        <Slider Name="sliderCalls"  TickFrequency="1" TickPlacement="BottomRight"  Minimum="0" Maximum="0"
            IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" ToolTip="Number of calls to dial the specified SIP URI" Width="736"/>
```

The corresponding image likes
[image: 1]

The textbox is visible. For some reason, I want to implement multiple selection that is similar a dropdown menu. The others are still same.

```
<Window x:Class="IVRLoadTester.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="IVR Load Test" Height="600" Width="800" >
<Window.Resources>
    <Geometry x:Key="ArrowIcon">M454.165,177.507L422.165,212.46 390.165,177.507 454.165,177.507z</Geometry>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Margin="10" >

    <Label Content="_Dial String:" Target="{Binding ElementName=txtDialString}" />

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DockPanel Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedString}" x:Name="cboText" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </DockPanel>
        <ToggleButton  Grid.Column="1" Width="30" Background="LightGray"
                       x:Name="ToggleDrop"    >

            <Path Data="{StaticResource ArrowIcon}"
                   Stretch="Uniform" Fill="Black" Width="10" Height="10" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            </Path>

        </ToggleButton>
        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ToggleDrop}"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=dp}"
               Placement="Bottom"
               Width="500"
               >
            <ListBox Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                 SelectionMode="Extended"  
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                 >
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
    <Label Content="_Number of Calls to Generate:" Target="{Binding ElementName=txtCalls}" />

    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">

        <TextBox Name="txtCalls" Text="{Binding ElementName=sliderCalls,
            Path=Value,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="22"/>

        <Slider Name="sliderCalls"  TickFrequency="1" TickPlacement="BottomRight"  Minimum="0" Maximum="0"
            IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" ToolTip="Number of calls to dial the specified SIP URI" Width="736"/>
```

The image becomes:
[image: 2]
You see the textbox is invisible. Why?
Also if I press the button, I got the graph as
[image: 3]

You see the pop up covers the label, that is not expected.

Please help these two questions.

Comment: PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=dp}"  
where's dp ?

Comment: @eranotzap, I got the help from a guy at http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/WPF-Multi-Select-Combo-d4b02a34.

Comment: that's great glad to ear it :) . 
by the way where's the element named "dp" that you wan't your popup to be placed at the 'Bottom' of ?

Comment: @eranotzap, I don't know. I haven't found the place to call "dp" in my code. I may ask him if necessary.

Comment: PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=cboText" you wan't to place it below this TextBox right ? , try posting only relevant xaml , it's really hard to read all that.

Comment: I changed it, but it is still covering the label.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59961/discussion-between-love-and-eran-otzap).

Answer (score 0):

First, pop up covers label since it has no space to display. Textblock under Dial String is actually placed there but not displaying anything, apparently SelectedString equals null.

Comment: First: Even `SelectedString` is null, the border of the textbox should be visible but it is not. Why? Secondly, I want to add pop up above the label. Dynamically add rows?

Comment: I suggest you to rebuild the whole view and use one Panel instead StackPanel, Grid, DockPanel concurrently. Element below "Dial String" is textblock not textbox.